# Jquery Validation does not start if mouse doesn't leave textbox the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I've only starting to use jquery validation plugin
And I'm using the most simplest form (see link attached)
However, i've notice a problem that i couldn't get an answer to, i've tried searching a whole different places

To reproduce the steps
1. Click into the name textbook
2. type any amount of letters (eg. abc)
3. backspace out everything
4. click or tab to the next textbook

This way jquery validation won't start, which is not what i want with the required rules. 
Please help, and thanks alot!

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form").validate({
      ignore: "",
      rules: {
         name: {
            required: true
               }
         },
         messages: {
            name: "Required Field"
         }
     });
});
```

And the HTML

```
<form id="form" method="" action="">
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <div><input type="text" id="name" name="name"> </div>
   <label for="what">What</label>
   <input type="text" id="what" name="what">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WW6fB/

Comment: It works for me in Firefox :(

Comment: it works in chrome http://pokit.org/get/?b8d762ce25b4658478763e17db9ed625.jpg

Comment: i've tried on IE10 and also Chrome, it doesn't work... Did you guys follow steps #1 to #4? It works if you click outside the textbox and come back (for me at least...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is the normal behaviour. If you add a submit button, the validation will trigger when the user tries to submit the form.
If you want to force validation on blur you can add this to the validate config object:

```
onfocusout: function(e) {
    this.element(e);
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9TUxn/

Comment: Thanks! But anyway to start validating ONLY when user start typing? Because in the real world, user might start typing something, then delete it and move to next entry, and i want it to check before they press submit